# Interface General Understanding

Tags: java, interface, charsequence

Good Evening Everybody!

During programming i used the CharSequence Interface ([Class Code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/CharSequence.java.html)):

```
CharSequence charSeq = "Java is cool!";

charSeq.length(); => Output: 13
```

I dont understand, how this works under hood:

1. Why can i do this: CharSequence charSeq = "Java is cool!"
2. Why can i do this: charSeq.length(), because there is no default Method in the interface, especially where is the implementation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you think `CharSequence charSeq = "Java is cool!";` does? What is `"Java is cool!"`?

Comment: [See the superinterfaces of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)